# How do I merge SE accounts?

Tags: support

Normally, when accessing a new SE site, my new account is merged with my old accounts when I first login, though for some reason this appears to have had issues when I created my Fitness.SE account.

Fitness.SE is showing up in my main SE account profile, but I did not get the automatically get the 100-rep that I normally get when creating an account on a new SE site, and my username is not being displayed correctly.

It's possible this is an SE issue, or an error on my part, but figured I'd ask on Fitness.SE first since I've been unable to figure out why this happen, and to my knowledge it's only happen on Fitness.SE; plus, I've been unable to figure out how to "correct it", though it's possible there's nothing to correct, and the issues I'm seeing were by design.

**UPDATE:** It's been a long, long time since I've had a rep below 100, and almost feel like I'm neglecting the question I asked on Fitness.SE, since I can't even upvote answers to my own question... as a result, I've [reposted the question to stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125561/how-do-i-merge-se-accounts), in an attempt to resolve the issue.

Comment: Appears to be a known bug across all SE sites:
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125439/just-created-an-account-on-a-new-se-site-wheres-my-100-rep -- lol, "Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 5 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead."

Comment: Yeah, there's a fix underway for this; for now, please be patient.

Comment: @blunders All fixes for this should be in place now. Has your association issue been corrected?